# Hortonworks HDP 2.5 Sandbox on a VM - download hangs

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

Trying to download Hortonworks HDP 2.5 Sandbox on a VM from the site:

[Hortonworks](http://hortonworks.com/downloads/#sandbox)

I click the 'Download for VMWare' button, and fill in the personal details form, but when I submit this the page just hangs. The submit button says 'Processing' and the clock/timer cycles in the centre of the screen, but no indication that it's downloading any files, even when left at it for several hours. I understand it's a big file, but I don't get a sense this is working.

I'm on Windows 10, using Chrome and with pop-up blocker switched off for the site.

Comment: Try in different browsers and download managers

Comment: Solved. Managed to download it on ie11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Managed to download ok on ie11.